# UTF-8 characters acting weird

Tags: utf-8

Okay my problem is that a couple of my special symbols show up as a little box, look here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLE7N.png

The symbol number is: \e8a1

The way it should look, and odly has no problem on this site is like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZU8Ol.png

I have forced upon UTF-8 via .htacces and no luck too. I've been trying for some time now.

Comment: That's a private use area character... you are missing a font for it.

Comment: @Esailija Anyway that I would actually be able to maybe detect the font for it?

Comment: There is no 'the font for it', it's private use area character so it can be anything depending on font.

Comment: Uhm ... context! HTML? Some UI Widget? Which browser? Which OS? Anything?

Comment: @Esailija I fail, this entire time the answer was in front of my face :P

.icon-logo-entypo:before

Entypo being the font :) downloaded and it's working now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fail, this entire time the answer was in front of my face :P .icon-logo-entypo:before Entypo being the font :) downloaded and it's working now!